# SQL 2019 Database Engine Service Stopped

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm having an issue with my new SQL 2019 server.  It seems that randomly the Database Engine service is stopping.  It has happened 4 times over the last 3 weeks.  There is no pattern as to what days/times it has been happening.  Here are some images from the log:
[image: Event Viewer]

[image: Event Details]

I really need help on this as my boss is on me to stop this from happening.  I'm open to any suggestions.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Look in the SQL Server error log and you'll find the stack dump.  If you can't find an answer by Googling, update with the latest CU, and if it occurs on the latest CU, then open an incident with Microsoft.  https://sqlserverupdates.com/sql-server-2019-updates/

Comment: Did you run DBCC CHECKDB as the error log says? Microsoft doc on that event id has some instructions, did you follow them? Please, check [17066](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-17066-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15).